# @Value resolving to null when running things from unit test

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I have following service class:

```
@Service
public class BidServiceImpl implements BidService {

    private final String apiUrl;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public BidServiceImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate,
                          @Value("${api.url}") String apiUrl){
        this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }


    public List<Bid> findAll() {
        ResponseEntity<Bid[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiUrl, Bid[].class);
        Bid[] bids = responseEntity.getBody();
        return Arrays.asList(bids);
    }
}
```

and following test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestBidService {

    @InjectMocks
    private BidServiceImpl bidService;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllReturnsListOfBids(){
        List<Bid> b = new ArrayList<>();
        Bid[] arr = new Bid[2];
        arr[1] = new Bid();
        arr[0] = new Bid();
        ResponseEntity<Bid[]> br = new ResponseEntity<>(arr, HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.getForEntity("url",Bid[].class)).thenReturn(br);
        List<Bid> bids = bidService.findAll();
        Assert.assertEquals(2,bids.size());
        Assert.assertTrue(bids instanceof List);
    }
}
```

when I run the unit test, I am getting a `NullPointerException` on `apiUrl`. which is injected as `@Value` in the my service class. The question is why it is not able to get the value from `application.properties` when I run the api and hit that service method via a controller everything works fine.

Comment: you are not loading the spring text context.you may need to use [SpringJunit4Runner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because all the `@MockitoJUnitRunner`, `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` are Mockito stuffs and they do not know anything about Spring. Hence they do not understand what `@Value` does and will not inject its value. The spring container even do not start in you case.

If you are using spring-boot and want Spring to inject this value , you can consider using `spring-boot-starter-test` starter and use its `@MockBean` to configure the Mockito mock :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestBidService { 

    @Autowired
    private BidServiceImpl bidService;

    @MockBean
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllReturnsListOfBids(){
       ///
    }
}
```

But it is an integration test as it will start up the whole spring container , so it is slower than the true unit test.

If you want the test to run as fast as possible , don't rely on Spring to inject that value for you. Simply set up by yourself:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestBidService {

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testFindAllReturnsListOfBids(){
        BidServiceImpl bidService = new BidServiceImpl(restTemplate , "http://127.0.0.1/");
        ////
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks...putting @SpringBootTest didn't work. It is still not able to inject that value, I double checked I have api.url=http://localhost:8080/bids in my applicatoin.properties.

Comment: change that `@InjectMocks`/ `@Mock` to `@Autowired` / `@MockBean` yet ?

Comment: hmm. just tried @Autowired and it works but its like creating real bean and creating all other bean that this bean depends on which is not good when unit testing. I am still wondering how this particular case will work with Mockito, because putting hard coded values doesn't make sense.

Comment: well , you get my point. It is not good to start the whole spring test container for unit test as it is slow . What i show is the idea to set that value by yourself rather tell spring to set the value to you as it require to start the spring container.  You don't need to hard code it , you can simply use `ClassPathResource` to load the properties from what location you like which is just a simple java problem ....

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @SpringBootTest is for integration tests and not unit tests! Also, I think your answer slightly deviates from the question (the problem is about @Value not being injected into `apiUrl` and not about restTemplate. `@Value("${api.url}") String apiUrl`

Comment: @ACV that 's why i explain to him why it cannot be injected and suggest a more elegant way to configure the value for the `apiUrl` rather than relies on spring to inject it.